# VBA Application: DAO.Databse/Recordset Reference Errors (Missing DLL)

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

Project Description: Excel Interface that opens/edits/closes an access database using variable types DAO.Database & DAO.Recordset in VBA.

Problem Statement: Some users do not have the correct dll mapped (ACEDAO.dll) in Access. This means the "Microsoft Office 15.0 Access database engine Object Library" is not an available reference under tools in the Access VBA window.

Current Progress in troubleshooting: I can open a blank Access database on the affected users PC, map to the correct dll, and the reference will appear and be checked. The excel interface will work fine, but only when the "dummy" database is already open. The "dummy" database can be closed and re-opened and the reference will still be there and be checked. So the current work-around is having affected users having to open a secondary database to use the Excel interface.

Thanks,
-JB-

Answer (score 0):

I would add this as a comment - but I don't have the rep yet to do so!

Have you tried [re-registering the DLL](https://www.sophos.com/en-us/support/knowledgebase/14343.aspx) on these users machines? You could try [this fix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2019235) too. Make sure the DLL file is also on the users machines - copy it from a working machine and put it in the same location.